# How can I make this overly edited question useful again?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I'm working on cleaning up questions and removing the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) from SO. I got to this question: [Problems implementing a quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133306/problems-implementing-a-quicksort) and I'm stuck here...

The question has been edited so many times it's become a community wiki. The big problem I have is that the OP edited out the question and just has an answer there now... which is pretty useless.

My gut instinct is to go back to version 1, then go through all the other edits and "cherry-pick" useful changes out of them. Does that make sense or am I going to far with this post?

Comment: Rollback to the latest question I'd say and take it from there. Perhaps leave a comment for the OP to create his own answer....what a mess.

Comment: You can take the OP's code posted as the answer and add it as a new answer (marked CW to indicate it's not your content, and with text indicating it's the OP's code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an answer here based on the comments so there's something acceptable:

- repost the OPs answer (marked as the OPs/CW)
- Once done roll back to the last time it was really a "question"

Makes sense and is a better option than starting over. I'll add to this putting on a comment asking OP to go accept the answer which is OPs answer anyway.

Comment: It would also be fair to make it community wiki, to indicate that it is not your content. For more on this see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: @Asad - Almost responded with "I did", then realized I hadn't. Good catch!

Comment: You don't have to make this (meta-answer) CW though, this is your own content. :)

Comment: @Asad - I guess not... but since how I handled it was based on Bart and Servy's suggestions (in the comments) I didn't feel right taking rep for the "answer"